# Getting Change Event to Fire in SyncFusion's SFAutoComplete Control

Tags: xamarin.ios, syncfusion

I am trying to use the SFAutoComplete control from SyncFusion in a Xamarin iPad app. (only iPad).

I am not able to get any sort of change event to fire.

What I've tried:

If you download SyncFusion and install it, it comes with a "SampleBrowser" app that has samples for all the controls in the suite.

If you open that SampleBrowser in visual studio and open the AutoComplete_Tablet.cs file after line 97, I've added this code:

```
 countryAutoComplete.ValueChanged += (sender, args) =>
 {
     suggestionModeLabel.Text = "IT WORKED!";
 };
```

But it never fires.

I've tried to use several different events from the list of events this control has (partial list from screenshot):

[image]

None of them seem to fire (I haven't tried ALL of them).

What do I need to do to get one of these events to fire? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using Syncfusion Controls.

**Delegate** property can be used to hook the SFAutoComplete's events as per in the following code example,

Declaration code for Delegate property

```
SFAutoComplete autocomplete = new SFAutoComplete();

autocomplete.Delegate = new SFAutoCompleteDelegate();
```

The way to hook the events in SFAutoComplete

```
public class SFAutoCompleteDelegate : AutoCompleteDelegate
    {
        public override void DidTextChange(SFAutoComplete SFAutoComplete, string value)
        {
            //It fired while changing the text in AutoComplete
        }
        public override void DidSelectionChange(SFAutoComplete SFAutoComplete, string value)
        {
            //It fired while changing the suggestion from suggestion box.
        }
    }
```

We have created a sample for achieving your requirement. Please download the same from the following link

Link:http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/125261/ze/testingAutoComplete_21799375630

Thanks & Regards,

Hemalatha M.R